# What are possible Haskell optimizations keys?

Tags: haskell, compiler-optimization

I found benchmark that solves really simple task in different languages https://github.com/starius/lang-bench . Here 's the code for Haskell :

```
cmpsum i j k =
    if i + j == k then 1 else 0

main = print (sum([cmpsum i j k |
    i <- [1..1000], j <- [1..1000], k <- [1..1000]]))
```

This code runs very slow as you can see in benchmark and I found this very strange. 
I tried to inline the function cmpsum and compile with the next flags:

```
ghc -c -O2 main.hs
```

but it really didn't help. I am not asking about optimizing the algorithm cause it's the same for all languages, but about possible compiler or code optimizations that can make this code run faster.

Comment: How slow is it? How does it compare to the C version?

Comment: @DavidYoung github benchmark shows next results : 
java  real    0m1.290s
haskell real    0m30.538s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are comparing looping over a single statement to counting by generating an intermediate structure (a list) and folding over it. I don't know how great the performance in Java would be if you created a linked list with a billion elements iterated over it.

Here is Haskell code which is (approximately) equivalent to your Java code.

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

main = print (loop3 1 1 1 0) 

loop1 :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
loop1 !i !j !k !cc | k <= 1000 = loop1 i j (k+1) (cc + fromEnum (i + j == k))
                   | otherwise = cc 

loop2 :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
loop2 !i !j !k !cc | j <= 1000 = loop2 i (j+1) k (loop1 i j k cc)
                   | otherwise = cc 

loop3 :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
loop3 !i !j !k !cc | i <= 1000 = loop3 (i+1) j k (loop2 i j k cc)
                   | otherwise = cc
```

And the execution on my machine (test2 is your Haskell code):

```
$ ghc --make -O2 test1.hs && ghc --make -O2 test2.hs && javac test3.java
$ time ./test1.exe && time ./test2.exe && time java test3
499500

real    0m1.614s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
499500

real    0m35.922s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
499500

real    0m1.589s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.015s
```

Comment: Nope. See jberryman's answer. The lists are never actually created (because of `foldr/build` fusion), but the arbitrary-precision integers *are*.

Comment: [A similar but shorter implementation](https://gist.github.com/2eb24b5d21ef07554d0b).  I haven't compared it to the java one, but it runs in ~2.3s on my machine.  BangPatterns didn't make a real difference in execution time, either.

Comment: [Got it faster and more imperative-looking](https://gist.github.com/53a34d6fc0359580a843).  Defined my own `for` function that generalizes the pattern, and it ends up being about twice as fast as my last test clocking in at ~1.1 to 1.2s on my machine.

Comment: @bheklilr, does the Core explain why your way works better than specializing the OP code to `Int`?

Comment: @dfeuer I haven't looked at the core yet, but my guess is that the simple recursion is easier to optimize than folding over a list, even with fusion and all that.

Comment: @bheklilr, desugaring produces just a single `build` form from the comprehension. `sum` translates to `foldl`, which the combination of arity analysis and demand analysis usually can handle properly. So I'm a bit surprised. But I want to go outside while it's light instead of poring over core.

Comment: By specializing cmpsum to Int (using the code from jberryman's answer), the time for the list version goes down to ~25s (from 35s). Still not even close to a version not using lists. I would have expected the list version to be slightly slower, but not so slow. Using the unboxed version of cmpsum actually increases it by about 2s. I'm still on 7.8.3, so I'm curious if there is some big performance difference between that and 7.10. 7.6.3 performs identically to 7.8.3, but I can't get 7.10 to test it right now.

Comment: @user2407038, yes, 7.10 has a new arity analysis supporting a new definition of `sum`, allowing it to fuse with "good producers" like list comprehensions. This erases the lists and allows the `Int`s  to be unboxed.

Comment: @dfeuer actually I took a quick peek at core, and it's doing lots of case-ing on lists, but I didn't investigate further

Comment: @dfeuer "arity analysis" - I looked it up it and it seems likes very cool stuff! Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @jberryman, if it's doing that with `Int` in 7.10, then something is a bit strange and might be a bug. See what happens if you manually expand `foldl'` into its `foldr` implementation.

Comment: @dfeuer, yeah see my updated answer. When I try a very simple `foldr/comprehension` pair on `[ i+j | i <- [0..10], j <- [0..10]]` it looks to me like only the first level is getting fused, so we get one intermediate list. Seems like that's at least a documentation bug

Comment: @dfeuer I know essentially nothing of Core or other lower-level optimizations, but for what it's worth, the brain-dead translation of C loops into Haskell folds is only around 2x slower than this answer and is much faster than the code jberryman posted. See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e82fa6dd41c23d4c4183). That took around 4.7 seconds to run on my machine compared to 2.0 seconds for this answer, 24.9 seconds for jberryman's code and 33.8 seconds for the original Haskell code.

Comment: FWIW I disagree that the haskell version isn't a valid translation of the C code. The lists are control structures, and from the documentation we ought to be assured that GHC optimizes them away.

Answer (score 9):

Not a complete answer, sorry. Compiling with GHC 7.10 on my machine I get ~12s for your version.

I'd suggest always compiling with `-Wall` which shows us that our numbers are being defaulted to the infinite precision `Integer` type. Fixing that:

```
module Main where

cmpsum :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
cmpsum i j k =
    if i + j == k then 1 else 0

main :: IO ()
main = print (sum([cmpsum i j k |
    i <- [1..1000], j <- [1..1000], k <- [1..1000]]))
```

This runs in ~5s for me. Running with `+RTS -s` seems to show we have a loop in constant memory:

```
          87,180 bytes allocated in the heap
           1,704 bytes copied during GC
          42,580 bytes maximum residency (1 sample(s))
          18,860 bytes maximum slop
               1 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0         0 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.000s     0.0000s    0.0000s
  Gen  1         1 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.000s     0.0001s    0.0001s

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.001s elapsed)
  MUT     time    4.920s  (  4.919s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  Total   time    4.920s  (  4.921s elapsed)

  %GC     time       0.0%  (0.0% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    17,719 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity 100.0% of total user, 100.0% of total elapsed
```

`-fllvm` shaves off another second or so. Maybe someone else can look into it further.

**Edit**: Just digging into this a little further. It doesn't look like fusion is happening. Even if I change `sum` to a `foldr (+) 0` which is an explicit ["good producer/good consumer"](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.3/docs/html/users_guide/rewrite-rules.html) pair.

```
Rec {
$wgo [InlPrag=[0], Occ=LoopBreaker] :: Int# -> Int#
[GblId, Arity=1, Str=DmdType <S,U>]
$wgo =
  \ (w :: Int#) ->
    let {
      $j :: Int# -> Int#
      [LclId, Arity=1, Str=DmdType]
      $j =
        \ (ww [OS=OneShot] :: Int#) ->
          letrec {
            $wgo1 [InlPrag=[0], Occ=LoopBreaker] :: [Int] -> Int#
            [LclId, Arity=1, Str=DmdType <S,1*U>]
            $wgo1 =
              \ (w1 :: [Int]) ->
                case w1 of _ [Occ=Dead] {
                  [] -> ww;
                  : y ys ->
                    case $wgo1 ys of ww1 { __DEFAULT ->
                    case lvl of _ [Occ=Dead] {
                      [] -> ww1;
                      : y1 ys1 ->
                        case y of _ [Occ=Dead] { I# y2 ->
                        case y1 of _ [Occ=Dead] { I# y3 ->
                        case tagToEnum# @ Bool (==# (+# w y2) y3) of _ [Occ=Dead] {
                          False ->
                            letrec {
                              $wgo2 [InlPrag=[0], Occ=LoopBreaker] :: [Int] -> Int#
                              [LclId, Arity=1, Str=DmdType <S,1*U>]
                              $wgo2 =
                                \ (w2 :: [Int]) ->
                                  case w2 of _ [Occ=Dead] {
                                    [] -> ww1;
                                    : y4 ys2 ->
                                      case y4 of _ [Occ=Dead] { I# y5 ->
                                      case tagToEnum# @ Bool (==# (+# w y2) y5) of _ [Occ=Dead] {
                                        False -> $wgo2 ys2;
                                        True -> case $wgo2 ys2 of ww2 { __DEFAULT -> +# 1 ww2 }
                                      }
                                      }
                                  }; } in
                            $wgo2 ys1;
                          True ->
                            letrec {
                              $wgo2 [InlPrag=[0], Occ=LoopBreaker] :: [Int] -> Int#
                              [LclId, Arity=1, Str=DmdType <S,1*U>]
                              $wgo2 =
                                \ (w2 :: [Int]) ->
                                  case w2 of _ [Occ=Dead] {
                                    [] -> ww1;
                                    : y4 ys2 ->
                                      case y4 of _ [Occ=Dead] { I# y5 ->
                                      case tagToEnum# @ Bool (==# (+# w y2) y5) of _ [Occ=Dead] {
                                        False -> $wgo2 ys2;
                                        True -> case $wgo2 ys2 of ww2 { __DEFAULT -> +# 1 ww2 }
                                      }
                                      }
                                  }; } in
                            case $wgo2 ys1 of ww2 { __DEFAULT -> +# 1 ww2 }
                        }
                        }
                        }
                    }
                    }
                }; } in
          $wgo1 lvl } in
    case w of wild {
      __DEFAULT -> case $wgo (+# wild 1) of ww { __DEFAULT -> $j ww };
      1000 -> $j 0
    }
end Rec }
```

In fact, looking at the core for `print $ foldr (+) (0:: Int) $ [ i+j | i <- [0..10000], j <- [0..10000]]` it seems as though only the first layer of the list comprehension is fused. Is that a bug?

Comment: Great answer,thanks. What's the reason that this code is still some times slower than code in the second version?

Comment: Remove the conditional jump from `cmpsum`. Use `{-#LANGUAGE MagicHash#-}` and `import GHC.Exts (I#, (+#), (==#))` and then define `cmpsum (I# i) (I# j) (I# k) = I# (i +# j ==# k)`. No guarantees, but it'll probably work. LLVM might be doing that already.

Comment: Ah, but then again, it's possible branch prediction is actually working right here, and you shouldn't interfere with it. Hmmmmmm.

Comment: Very interesting update. I think I know what's happening here: GHC sees that the three lists are constant, and all but the first are used multiple times. Therefore, it makes the mistake of pulling the constant expressions out of the loop (probably in the first full laziness pass) before the `enumFromTo` expressions have had a chance to inline and fuse with `foldr`. I bet you could hack around it by using `j <- [1 .. foo 1000 i]` and `k <- [1 .. foo 1000 j]`, where `foo` is a `NOINLINE` version of `const`, but this is definitely troubling, and the compiler gurus may want to make an adjustment.

Answer (score 6):

This code gets the job done in 1 second and no extra allocation in GHC 7.10 with `-O2` (see the bottom for profiling output):

```hs
cmpsum :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
cmpsum i j k = fromEnum (i+j==k)

main = print $ sum [cmpsum i j k | i <- [1..1000],
                                   j <- [1..const 1000 i],
                                   k <- [1..const 1000 j]]
```

In GHC 7.8, you can get almost the same results in this case (1.4 seconds) if you add the following at the beginning:

```
import Prelude hiding (sum)

sum xs = foldr (\x r a -> a `seq` r (a+x)) id xs 0
```

There are three issues here:

1. Specializing the code to `Int` instead of letting it default to `Integer` is crucial.
2. GHC 7.10 offers list fusion for `sum` that GHC 7.8 does not. This is because the new definition of `sum`, based on a new definition of `foldl`, can be very bad in some cases without the "call arity" analysis Joachim Breitner created for GHC 7.10.
3. GHC performs a limited "full laziness" pass very early in compilation, before any inlining occurs. As a result, the constant `[1..1000]` terms for `j` and `k`, which are used multiple times in the loop, get hoisted out of the loop. This would be good if these were actually expensive to calculate, but in this context it's much cheaper to do the additions over and over and over instead of saving the results. What the code above does is trick GHC. Since `const` isn't inlined until a little bit later, this first full laziness pass doesn't see that the lists are constant, so it doesn't hoist them out. I wrote it this way because it's nice and short, but it is, admittedly, a little on the fragile side. To make it more robust, use phased inlining:

   ```
   main = print $ sum [cmpsum i j k | i <- [1..1000],
                                      j <- [1..konst 1000 i],
                                      k <- [1..konst 1000 j]]

   {-# INLINE [1] konst #-}
   konst = const
   ```

   This guarantees that `konst` will be inlined in simplifier phase 1, but no earlier. Phase 1 occurs *after* list fusion is complete, so it's perfectly safe to let GHC see everything then.

```
          51,472 bytes allocated in the heap
           3,408 bytes copied during GC
          44,312 bytes maximum residency (1 sample(s))
          17,128 bytes maximum slop
               1 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0         0 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.000s     0.0000s    0.0000s
  Gen  1         1 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.000s     0.0002s    0.0002s

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  MUT     time    1.071s  (  1.076s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  Total   time    1.073s  (  1.077s elapsed)

  %GC     time       0.0%  (0.0% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    48,059 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  99.9% of total user, 99.6% of total elapsed
```

Comment: Awesome detective work! There ought to be a ticket for this I think; did you happen to check?

Comment: @jberryman, I opened one once for something very similar. It turns out to be a bit of a Hard Problem to know when to do what with these things, based on what the gurus said :-/. One of several hard problems is that full laziness is a rather wild transformation that's not always good, but GHC depends on it quite heavily to support other transformations.